# Poner configuración editable en WAR

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto ya hecho. Tengo un archivo XML en `<mi proyecto>/src/main/resources/dao/daoBeans.xml` donde se encuentran todos los datos de la DB (host, puerto, user, contraseña, etc). El problema es que cuando lo exporto a un WAR esos seteos se compilan y no se pueden editar una vez exportado. Lo que buscamos es poder "externalizar" el archivo para compilar el proyecto una sola vez y en el caso de que se cambie algún dato no se tenga que compilarlo entero nuevamente.

Los seteos se cargan con la línea:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"dao/daoBeans.xml"});
```

Por ende, no puedo copiar y pegar el daoBeans.xml en WEB-INF cosa de que no sea compilado ya que ClassPathXmlApplicationContext al parecer utiliza rutas relativas empezando dentro de `src`.

Espero haber sido claro, desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final vi que dentro del WAR quedan las carpetas `/lib/classes/dao` y ahí encontré mi archivo daoBeans.xml, lo edité y salió andando de 10 con los nuevos parámetros como esperaba.

Con respecto a la respuesta de Ventur, tanto la clase `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` como `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` tienen el mismo efecto en cuanto a la exportación de los archivos (ambos dejan el .xml donde mencioné anteriormente y ambas manejan las mismas rutas relativas) por lo que no resolvía mi problema en particular.

Answer (score 1):

Hola buen día con Spring tienes la clase  [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html)

> Standalone XML application context, taking the context definition
>   files from the file system or from URLs, interpreting plain paths as
>   relative file system locations (e.g. "mydir/myfile.txt"). Useful for
>   test harnesses as well as for standalone environments.

Dicho en otras palabras permite cargar archivos de configuración desde el file System y cumple con lo que buscas, tener la configuración fuera del EAR, WAR o JAR.

Ejemplo:

```
private static final String URL_XML= "/home/config/daoBeans.xml";

ApplicationContext ctx = null;
ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:"+URL_XML);
```

Ahora si quieres integrar configuración XML a tus EJB , podrás  hacer lo siguiente:

> **benRefContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- load a hierarchy of contexts, although there is just one here -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="servicelayer-context"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
      <list>
        <value>file:/home/businessConfig.xml</value>
        <value>file:/home/Globals.xml</value>
        <value>file:/home/Records.xml</value>
        <value>file:/home/businessService.xml</value>
        <value>file:/home/daos.xml</value>
      </list>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Hola, con esa clase que me pasaste no me queda como exportado en el WAR. Pero acabo de notar que tanto con `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` como con `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` queda en la carpeta `WEB-INF\classes\dao\daoBeans.xml` del WAR! Ahora voy a probar si funciona cambiando los parametros dentro del WAR compilado! Gracias por responder!

Comment: En tu clase donde creas tu objeto para leer el xml, simplemente indicas de donde lo tomara, al momento de generar el WAR evidentemente ya no veras el xml como parte del WAR, ahora  cuando lo instales en un ambiente DEV, UAT o PROD, deberás asegurar que el XML de configuración este en la ruta indicada.

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/LoadconfigwithFileSystemXmlApplicationContext.htm ,  tus xml los puedes colocar  sin problema en file System

Comment: Este diseño sugiere que el XML de configuración de Spring esté fuera del path. Me parece que es algo muy drástico para este proyecto cuando solo se necesita externalizar la configuración a la base de datos. Para eso, se puede usar un archivo properties y obtener sus valores usando `property-placeholder` o `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` para múltiples archivos properties.

Comment: Claro, dependerá exactamente que tantos mapeos tiene en su dao.xml, si solo son parámetros de conexión o `n` mapeos. Tiempo atrás el cliente solicito sacar del proyecto toda la configuracion(más de 100 objetos  mapeados). Pero si el compañero  así lo quiere que se pueda hacer ^^

Comment: Ahí añadí una respuesta donde explico como solucioné el problema! Gracias igual por responder! Doy puntos por la voluntad y la molestia de responder! Gracias nuevamente!